# Mongoose.js - population and additional fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I want to add some additional data to **UserModel** like **watchedMovies** and I have following schema:

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
  watchedMovies: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Movie'
  }]
})
```

and:

```
let movieSchema = new Schema({
  title: String
})
```

I was wondering is it possible to add any additional fields to **watchedMovies** object and store it along with ObjectId? I would like to add **watchedAt** date so when I'm populating **watchedMovies** with `UserModel.find().populate('watchedMovies', 'title').exec(...)` I would get something like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(UserId),
  watchedMovies: [{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    title: 'Some title',
    watchedAt: TimeStamp
  }]
}
```

**watchedAt** attribute specifies when (Date object) reference was added to UserModel

**Is it possible with mongoose and how should I change my schema?**

Thank You

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what the `Movie` model mongoose schema is like?

Comment: Oh, yes, just edited that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your schema to

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
  watchedMovies: [{
    movie: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Movie'
    },
    watchedAt: Date
  }]
})
```

then you can populate by `.populate('watchedMovies.movie')`

Comment: I know that, but the question is not about that.

Comment: what exactly is your question about, then? to me it sounds like you're asking how to get more fields than just the title back when you use `.populate`. that's not a very helpful way to respond to an incorrect answer

Comment: When I'm adding reference to user model (reference of movie) I would like to store a timestamp when was that reference saved, i.e. to know when user watched that movie

Comment: I just tried that and it seems that it does not work. Is it supposed to work and I'm doing something wrong, or you try to guess the implementation? :)

Comment: Don't know what happened yesterday (probably it was already too late) but now in the morning after trying again - it seems to just be working as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: how to do the insert if I'm using above schema